# Why someone would use a hexadecimal approach in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, design-patterns, hex

I apologize cause this may be a bizarre question but I'm pretty confused.  Would anyone know why someone would use what I believe to be "a hexadecimal approach" to javascript?  i.e.) I see someone naming variables like

```
_0x2f8b, _0xcb6545,_0x893751, _0x1d2177, etc
```

Why would anyone ever do this?  Also, I see code like

```
'to\x20bypass\x20this\x20link'
```

as well as hexadecimals for numbers such as 725392

```
0xb1190
```

So, how would anyone even get this kind of naming convention and why would they ever want to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like this has been, 99% of the time, *automatically* mangled/obfuscated from the original source code, in an attempt to make it more difficult to reverse engineer.

For example, if you start with

```
const foo = 'bar';
const somethingElse = 5;
```

you might use [an obfuscation tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=obfuscate+js) to come up with

```
var _0x2f8b, _0xcb6545;
_0x2f8b = 'bar';
_0xcb6545 = 5;
```

and serve *that* to clients. Reading 200 lines of obfuscated code is a lot harder than reading 200 lines of the original source code.

> as well as hexadecimals for numbers such as 725392

Same thing - it's easier for a human to make sense of 725392 (which may be a magic number important for the application) than 0xb1190.

This isn't something that would be present in *source* code.

Comment: ya you must be right the console.log is turned off.

Comment: Do you know how to "un-obfuscation" code?

Comment: It's not possible. Once the original variable names have been changed, you can't revert them back to their original ones - that would defeat the purpose of obfuscation.